# Why are folders with weird names automatically appearing on my Desktop?

Tags: filesystem

Many of these weird folders show up all the time with these titles: 00, 0a, 0b... 0f;  01, 1a, 1b...1f;  02, 2a, 2b...2f;  03, 3a, 3b... 3f; etc up to ff. Why? What is this? What can I do to stop it?
They come back when I throw them out, which I've done many times
here are some screen shots to give you an idea:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any scripts or codes on your system?

Comment: You can download **Etrecheck** : https://etrecheck.com and create a report to see if you have some troubles or malwares on your Mac. If you don't understand this report, you can add it to your question by a **Pastebin link**. This report does not contain private information. The free version of **MalwareBytes** : https://fr.malwarebytes.com/mac/ can help you.

Comment: You might get a clue by looking at what is inside the folders. Possibly more folders, but drill down until you get to some files. Tell us what you find.

Answer (score -1):

They look suspiciously like folders from a iPhone or iPod backup, which is typically not found on the desktop (normally found in ~/Library/Application Support/Mobile Sync/Backup//

If so, the backup would consist of a folder with an iPhone ID as a name and all those folders you see inside it. The folders have 2 character names. Inside one of these folders (say 00) are feels with file names starting with the name of the folder. One example filename for me is 00aabeab60f635dc810b27b8b884e90115caef61. All characters would be hex digits.

In iTunes Preferences under Devices you can see the individual backups, if any. Selecting one, then right-clicking will pop up a menu with the choice "Show in Finder". If this is what it is, then a new window should open showing where the backup is.

It could be some other Apple generated backup as well.